# access mongodb from flash builder / actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mongodb, flash-builder

Is there a way to directly communicate with a mongodb server from a flash builder 4 AIR / actionscript (cli?) application?

I know it is possible to use AMF - for example through Zend AMF (PHP), but I was hoping for this particular application to eliminate that hop or overhead and communicate directly with the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found someone developing an action script driver, but looks like it is incomplete:

https://github.com/s9tpepper/MongoAS3

Answer (score 1):

Here you will find a full driver for MongoDB flex and AS3 : http://code.google.com/p/jmcnet-full-mongo-flex-driver/

Main features are :

```
connexion pooling,
Safe mode enabling,
Direct CRUD object manipulation,
Full Aggregation support (group, MapReduce, ...),
BSON encoder and decoder,
ObjectID helper.
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has a REST interface that would be trivial to interface with in Flex:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface

Comment: It looks like that is a read only interface?    It does mention a couple other 3rd party REST interfaces - one looks like it is a python front end, the other mentions using some kind of native driver, though it looks linux oriented and I am running on Windows...

Answer (score 0):

Check out [MongoAS3 by @s9tpepper](http://www.mongoas3.com/):

> An ActionScript 3 driver for mongodb that works without the use of a
>   server side language such as PHP, Java, .Net, etc. The driver is
>   written in pure AS3 so it is usable in both pure AS3/Flash projects as
>   well as Flex projects.